# Wubi can't detect local copy of ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso

Tags: wubi

This is driving me nuts...

Wubi.exe is running with a perfect copy (MD5 checked) of Ubuntu 12.04.2 Desktop AMD64 alongside. Yet it does not detect it somehow, and attempts to download a fresh copy. My internet is terrible for downloading at the moment, and I need the installation as soon as possible.

[Log output](http://pastebin.com/chi4Amc9)

**Note:** the lines

```
07-28 15:55 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running get_iso...
07-28 15:55 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Could not find any ISO or CD, downloading one now
```

Anyone want to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They changed the kernel from `vmlinuz` to `vmlinuz.efi` from release 12.04.1. So the only way to get around this is to use the patched revision 273 of `wubi.exe` for Ubuntu 12.04.2 here: http://people.canonical.com/~evand/wubi/precise/wubi-r273-signed.exe

It was patched and built, but the fix was only released for 13.04 and not 12.04.2 for some reason. (See https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/1134770)